# IntelliJ: How to make Maven project use only the dependencies show in pom.xml file

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml, dependency-management

I open a new Maven Project by navigating to File -> New -> Project -> Maven -> mark "Create from archetype" -> org.apache.maven.archetypes: maven-archetype-quickstart" -> ...

What I see is that this operation brings all the jars inside .m2/repository to the classpath of the project.

What I want is that only the dependencies that are mentioned in pom.xml file will be used in classpath. For example, if the pom.xml has dependencies on packages A and B, and the .m2/repository path includes a C package (probably from another project), then my project will not resolve symbols of package C.

Do you know how to do it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Are you sure there is no transitive dependency from project A or B onto C ?
That is does A pom.xml , or B pom.xml have a dependency to C ?

Comment: That is not how it works, each dependency has transitive dependency (i.e. they depend on other libraries themselves). The very nature of Maven is to handle those transitive dependencies so that your application works. And if those dependencies require transitive dependencies to run, you will have to have them also.

Comment: OK. But what if I write code and I forgot to mention a dependency I need in the pom.xml file? Maybe my code works because I already installed this dependency in one of my previous projects (so it's in .m2), but once I deploy this project to a remote computer, the project will get an error,

Comment: @CrazySynthax *"what if I write code and I forgot to mention a dependency"* as long as you don't manually change the IDEs "build path" maven handles this correctly. It does not simply include all available jars in your local repository. It may look like this because you only have a single project and maven just downloaded all needed jars. Try this: copy your project, change the `artefactId`, remove the `<dependencies>` completely and check the copies "build path",

Answer (score 3):

It is a core feature of **Maven** that it resolves transitive dependencies. Theses artifacts are downloaded and added to the classpath automatically.

But there may be circumstances, where you don't want a transitive dependency to be fetched. Look at this diagram:

[image]

Here, you can prevent the artifact C2 from getting fetched by maven with the `<exclusions>` element:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>DepB</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.example</groupId>
                <artifactId>DepC2</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The artifacts in your local repository (`~/.m2/repository` by default) are **available** for the usage in every of your projects, there **are not included automatically** in the projects classpath, but they are included when they are needed (maybe as transitive dependencies). My local repository contains about 5000 artifacts ...

The concept of the local maven repository is a replacement for that what is called "Libraries" in IntelliJ and Eclipse, too.